# My understanding of chromosomes and the processes related to them is lacking

Tags: homework, chromosome, meiosis, mitosis, allele

I'm sorry for the incredibly simple question, I just can't seem to find any answers elsewhere online.
I am a high school student currently studying for the upcoming AP biology exam, and recently I have realised that I do not quite understand chromosomes. To be specific, I understand what they are (the condensed form of chromatin that one sees when viewing a dividing cell), but my understanding is still lacking when it comes to:

- Ploidy, specifically when it changes.
- Alleles and how they move/interact during meiosis.
- How homologous chromosomes work: When do they occur? Is each chromatid pair identical, or is one chromatid in each pair from each parent?

I made a diagram that details my current understanding, because it can be a bit difficult to describe what I *don't* understand, but I can try to elaborate more if necessary.
[image: my current understanding of chromosome behaviour]

If this is the wrong sort of place to ask this question, some advice on a better place to ask would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.